# How can I toggle the switch if the ringing volume change?

Tags: java, android, volume, android-audiomanager

I want max volume when I launch the app so I getStreamMaxVolume in the onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swVolume = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);     
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int vol = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    int maxVol = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    am.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
            am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
            0);
```

then I want the switch to be turned On if the Volume is at max

```
    if(vol == maxVol){
        swVolume.setChecked(true);

    }
```

and turned Off when the volume is not at max

```
    if(vol < maxVol){
            swVolume.setChecked(false);
      }
    else {
            swVolume.setChecked(false);
      }
```

Can someone pls explain to me why isn't the code working? is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Try debugging between your lines:
Log.d("vol & maxvol", "vol = " + vol + ", maxvol = " + maxvol);
And see if your values concord.

Comment: vol = 0 , maxVol = 15

Comment: Well clearly you're not listening for changes in the volume since you're doing it in the "onCreate". Try putting your volume to the max and then launch, it should work since it does the check in your onCreate. You have to listen for changes in the volume with a listener and adapt the swVolume to it.